# SSRS Selective Page Break

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm having some formatting issues in SSRS with a current report I'm working on concerning property records.  My report is built with 6 tablixes aligned in a landscape view meant to remain in a specific layout for potential printing of the report.

The first Tablix contains general information about the property in question and the owner.  This information will be completely static and should remain the same.

The second Tablix is the problem.  This Tablix is formatted to pull data from a stored procedure concerning parcels of land and generate up to 13 rows, filling in NULL values if less than 13 rows of data exist.  The issue is if MORE than 13 rows of data exist.  Currently, the result I have stretches the report and messes up the formatting entirely with 14 or more rows.

There are 4 other tablixes below this Tablix that contain additional details about the property, including buildings, outbuildings, and general appraisal summaries for the property.  These will remain the same, as well.  Each of these tablixes pulls from its own data set and has a stored procedure to generate the rows as needed.

My goal is to generate a report that contains up to 13 rows of land data on the first page and with any additional rows, keep the same exact page layout, but with the land data Tablix filled with rows 14-26 on a second page.  That is, the layout from the first page of the report is repeated but with the remaining rows of data within the land data Tablix.

I've included the layout of the form for reference and I'm currently using Report Builder 2012 with MSSQL. The Land Section Detail is the Tablix in question.

[Report View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKHR6.png)

Honestly, I'm not sure that this is possible, but I'm open to any suggestions on how to make this work.

EDIT: Changed the picture to provide a better idea of what I have.

EDIT: Adding "Sample Data"
[Also a Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=423d175827f8c867a1c1b951c88b531f)

[Best sample I can offer considering the size of the data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iipUC.png)

Comment: please provide sample data, and an example of what you want the report to look like when you have more than 13 rows to report.

Comment: @Brian I'm not able to provide sample data as the data I'm working with is sensitive.  As far as what the report should look like... The same.  Additional pages should look exactly the same as the first page shown in the picture above.  I simply want Tablix 2 on Page 2 to print the next 13 rows of data. All other fields should remain the same on Page 2.

Comment: Then make some dummy data.  Bear in mind that the only person who has been working on this project, and is familiar with it, is you.  The rest of us must "come up to speed" in order to help you - the easier you make that to do, the more likely you are to get assistance.

Comment: @Brian I understand that, but the data is irrelevant -- this is a formatting issue.  These are parcels of land owned by the same person/corporation.  Each parcel is a number of acres, has a value per acre, total appraised value, etc.  The point is, the "#" column should count 1-13 on the first page with all tablixes laid out exactly as pictured.  The second page should be a duplicate page, but the "#" column should count 14-26 in the Land Section Details Tablix.  Basically, 2 identical pages - only difference should be Land Section Details as described.

Comment: I understand that it's a formatting issue.  That formatting issue, however, depends on the number of records being returned, and "number of records being returned" is a data issue.  That's why I've asked, twice now, for sample data.  The SO pages on [ask] and [mcve] will explain my request further.  If you don't want to provide dummy data that represents the size and shape of your dataset, so be it.  I wish you luck.

Comment: @Brian Did the best I could considering the size of the dataset...  SQLFiddle kept giving me errors and ASCII table generator wouldn't take the data from dbfiddle.uk to any decent format, nor would a simple copypasta turn in anything remotely viewable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue with a somewhat complex method, but a method that worked perfectly for the report.  The basic idea was to use a temporary table to keep all of the data aligned with a row count and page number in each dataset.  With that row count, I was able to determine a cut-off point for each page.  For example, if a Tablix had room for 9 rows of data, each of the first 9 rows of data were assigned the page number 1.  Rows 10-18 would be assigned page number 2.  In this way, I was able to group the report based on the page number.

If no data was assigned to a given page, I had an additional dataset that generated the correct number of blank rows to fill the same gap and maintain the correct page layout.

Answer (score 0):

I once had the same problem to limit the row numbers of a tablix. This description was the solution:

[Display a fixed number of rows](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3493/display-a-fixed-number-of-rows-per-page-for-an-ssrs-report/)

Comment: That solution combined with a List control should be able to repeat the multiple tablixes per page.

Comment: @DaleBurrell How would the List control factor in?  Are you suggesting that each Tablix be placed inside a List?  And is it possible to page break after the list based on the Tablix group nested in the list?

Comment: @Steve-o169 A `List Control` can be used to split on the first group on the dataset and to repeat its contents (on a new page) for each unique grouped item. So for financial reports you could group by currency using the list control and then list the details within. Whether that approach will work with the solution here I don't know, but worth investigating.

Comment: @DaleBurrell I actually looked into List controls a bit before you responded here and I believe there's an issue with my report in that each Tablix refers to its own dataset and the List control wants it to all refer to one dataset.  I may just have to alter my report format as this is proving an elusive goal.