# SSRS Joining Records With Different Values in Same Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

So I'm not really sure how to word this and I'm fairly new to using SQL in a professional setting but I hope I come across clearly.  First, my data looks like this:

```
+--------+-----------+-------------+------------------+ 
| LandID | LandUnits | LandLineNum | TaxableLandValue |
+--------+-----------+-------------+------------------+ 
| 36512  | 19        | 6           | 8129             | 
| 36513  | 25        | 4           | 20638            | 
| 36514  | 5         | 3           | 18484            |
| 36515  | 95        | 5           | 78530            | 
| 36516  | 73        | 2           | 260560           | 
| 36517  | 1         | 1           | 20528            | 
| 36518  | 25        | 104         | 6500             | 
| 36519  | 73        | 102         | 57541            | 
| 36520  | 1         | 101         | 20528            | 
| 36521  | 19        | 106         | 1281             | 
| 36522  | 95        | 105         | 19977            | 
| 36523  | 5         | 103         | 3068             |
+--------+-----------+-------------+------------------+
```

These `LandID` Sections are all related by a single `PropertyID` from another table -- referenced through a bridge table(`PropertyToLand`).  So basically, these 12 records relate to the same property owner and constitute 6 parcels of land owned by one person.  If you look carefully at this data, you'll see that `LineNum` 1-6 line up with their respective `LandUnit` count on `LineNum` 101-106, but the `TaxableLandValue` is different between those records.

Don't ask me why the table was built this way, but basically, I need `TaxableLandValues` from `LineNum` 1-6 for one field in an SSRS report and the `TaxableLandValues` from `LineNum` 101-106 for another field without modifying the table.

Currently, `SELECT TaxableLandValue` in my stored procedure successfully grabs the values for 1-6 while I've been filtering out the other results based on another column `ZoningID` which is `NULL` in the 101-106 records, otherwise all 12 records are added to the report.

Basically, I need to figure out the best way to join `LineNum` 1 with `LineNum` 101 and so on, in a way that I can isolate the different `TaxableLandValue` results.

My current SQL procedure creates a table with 15 columns, I'll try to condense my code to display the problem.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE rpt_LandData
   @PropertyID INT

CREATE TABLE #temp (
LandID VARCHAR(50), 
LandUnits INT, 
LandLineNum INT, 
TaxableLandValue VARCHAR(50),
TaxableUseValue VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #temp(
l.LandID AS LandId, 
l.LandUnits AS LandUnits, 
l.LandLineNum AS LandLineNum, 
l.TaxableLandValue AS TaxableLandValue,
l.TaxableLandValue AS TaxableUseValue)

FROM t_Land l
INNER JOIN t_PropertyToLand ptl ON l.LandID=ptl.LandID
INNER JOIN t_Property p ON ptl.PropertyID=p.PropertyID

WHERE ptl.PropertyID = @PropertyID AND l.ZoningID IS NOT NULL

SELECT * FROM #temp 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN LandLineNum IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, LandLineNum ASC
```

I've tried various methods which include removing the filter on `ZoningID` and instead using a `(SELECT TaxableLandValue FROM t_Land WHERE ZoningID IS NULL) AS TaxableUseValue` but this is something I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around.

My expected result would look like this:

```
+--------+-----------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| LandID | LandUnits | LandLineNum | TaxableLandValue | TaxableUseValue |
+--------+-----------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 36517  | 1         | 1           | 20528            | 20528           |
| 36516  | 73        | 2           | 260560           | 57541           |
| 36514  | 5         | 3           | 18484            | 3068            |
| 36513  | 25        | 4           | 20638            | 6500            |
| 36515  | 95        | 5           | 78530            | 19977           |
| 36512  | 19        | 6           | 8129             | 1281            |
+--------+-----------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

Thanks in advance for any help and let me know if you need more information.
Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I've been unable to locate any related questions.

Comment: join on `LandLineNum = LandLineNum+100`?   Is there some reason it isn't that simple?

Comment: @TabAlleman Would you mind providing an example of what that would look like in the context of my procedure?  You're suggesting an additional `JOIN` statement joining Land to itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I greatly appreciate the help from @TabAlleman and I was able to resolve my issue thanks to his input, though the answer given was not quite the solution I was looking for.  I was able to find the correct answer by joining `t_Land` to itself on `LandLineNum - 100` but also had to verify that the parameter being called matched both `t_Property` tables that were being joined.

```
SELECT  l.LandID AS LandID,
    l.LandLineNum AS LineNum, 
    l.LandValueTaxable AS TaxValues,
    la.LandLineNumber AS LineNum2,
    la.LandValueTaxable AS UseValues
     FROM t_Land l 
LEFT JOIN t_Land la ON l.LandLineNum = la.LandLineNum - 100
LEFT JOIN t_PropertyToLand prl ON l.LandID = prl.LandID
LEFT JOIN t_Property pr ON prl.PropertyID = pr.PropertyID
LEFT JOIN t_PropertyToLand prl2 ON la.LandID = prl2.LandID
LEFT JOIN t_Property pr2 ON prl2.Property_ID = pr2.Property_ID

WHERE pr.PropertyID = @PropertyID AND pr2.PropertyID = @PropertyID
```

Answer (score 1):

As an example of the suggestion in my comment, you could do something like this in your FROM clause:

(edited based on comment)

```
...
FROM  t_Land l 
INNER JOIN t_Land u ON l.LandID=u.LandID AND l.LandLineNum = u.LandLineNum - 100
{This may require TWO joins to t_PropertyToLand, I can't say since you haven't shared your full table structure}
...
```

And then `l.TaxableLandValue` would have your land value, and `u.TaxableLandValue`  would have your use value.

You'd have to include some filter to prevent the `linenum`s over 100 to be counted in the `l` results.

Comment: That likely won't work as written as `LandLineNum` is a field in the `Land` table, not the `PropertyToLand` which only bridges the `Land` records to its corresponding owners in `Property`. `INNER JOIN` seems to result in all `NULL` values when I tried to adapt this solution. With 
`LEFT JOIN t_Land l ON ptl.Land_ID = l.Land_ID` 
`LEFT JOIN t_Land la ON l.Land_ID = la.Land_ID AND la.LandLineNum = l.LandLineNum - 100`
results in `NULL` values only in the `TaxableUseValue` column.

Comment: Yes I had to guess at your table structure since it wasn't fully shared.   I have edited the answer based on your comment.

Comment: I guess the problem I've having is my own fault but my intention was to be more concise and simple.  Currently, `Land` is `LEFT JOIN`ed with 8 other tables to fill out the 15 fields required for the report and `INNER JOIN` seems to kill my other joins and results in all fields coming back `NULL`.  `Land` contains about 30 columns, `Property` contains 75 columns, and `PropertyToLand` only 6, being a PK, `PropertyID`, `LandID`, and 3 timestamps. If it helps, I have another open question with the report shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53744617/ssrs-selective-page-break